# Unable to exit from voice tutorial in Nexus 5

Tags: nexus-5

i ve bought a new Nexus 5. But I am unable to exit from the voice tutorial that is going on. How do I disable the voice tutorial that is running on my phone? Please help...

Comment: what do u mean by voice tutorial??

Answer (score -1):

i opted factory reset and started all over again but without signing in gmail account and it worked     the nagging voice tutorial is gone